# No known class method for selector in objectiveC class found written in swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift4, xcode10.1

I have written one class function in one swift class then trying to access the same from one objectiveC class getting No known class method for selector 'myMethodName'. I have also done `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"` . It was working properly with Xcode below 10.1 . Please help me at the earliest. Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

typealias LoginCompletionHandler = (_: Bool) -> Void

class SCLoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var myLoginCompletionBlock: LoginCompletionHandler? = nil
    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    //PRAGMA:- Class Methods
    class func showOnNavigation(navigationController:UINavigationController, completionBlock:@escaping LoginCompletionHandler) {
        let vc = SCLoginViewController.init(nibName: "SCLoginViewController", bundle: nil)
        vc.myLoginCompletionBlock = completionBlock
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}


#import "LoginOptionVC.h"
#import "Project-Swift.h"

@interface LoginOptionVC () <>

@end

@implementation LoginOptionVC


- (instancetype)initWithBarButtonType:(BarButtonType)btnType showClubLogo:(BOOL)showLogo onCompletion:(CompletionHandler) completionBlock {

    self = [[ClubLoginOptionVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClubLoginOptionVC" bundle:nil];

    if (self) {
        self.myCompletionBlock = completionBlock;
    }

    return self;
}


#pragma mark - View LifeCycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
- (IBAction)clickLogin:(id)sender {
    [SCLoginViewController showOnNavigationWithNavigationController:self.navigationController completionBlock:^(BOOL isSuccess) {
        if (isSuccess) {
            NSLog(@"logged in ");
        }

        if (self.myCompletionBlock) {
            self.myCompletionBlock(isSuccess);
        }
    }];
}
}
```

Comment: try defining the function with `@objc` attribute: `@obj class func showOnNavigation(navigationController:UINavigationController, completionBlock:@escaping LoginCompletionHandler)`

Comment: Thanks for the help it's working now.

Answer (score 5):

Addition to Scriptable's answer. If you want to expose all function to Objective-C in a class. Then add `@objcMembers` attribute.

```
@objcMembers class MyController: UIViewController {
   class func showOnNavigation(navigationController:UINavigationController, completionBlock:@escaping LoginCompletionHandler) {

   }
}
```

By way of adding @objcMembers attribute in a class, you no need to add `@objc` attribute in functions.

Comment: This looks great! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Add the @objc attribute to the func to expose the Swift code to Objective-C

```
@obj class func showOnNavigation(navigationController:UINavigationController, completionBlock:@escaping LoginCompletionHandler)
```